# Cannot call value of non-function type 'Bundle' using Xcode 15 beta-1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15, ios17

I am trying to build my project using Xcode 15 for iOS 17.

So far I have solved many errors, but I am stuck with this one.

[image: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Bundle']

From my understanding `GeneratedAssetSymbols` is an auto-generated file created by Xcode to list the resources within your `Assets.xcassets` catalog.

I can't figured out why this file can't access the initializer `Bundle(for: aClass: AnyClass)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem that we defined a global `Bundle` in our code.

```swift
let Bundle = Foundation.Bundle.main
```

We only needed to rename it as such.

```swift
let MyBundle = Foundation.Bundle.main
```